# How to move all files from a directory(including subdirectories) to a specific directory without subdirectories in target using camel route over FTP?

Tags: java, routes, ftp, apache-camel, ftp-client

As I am very new to **Apache-Camel**, I stuck with a use case.
I want to achieve moving of all files to a specific directory without sub-directories in target using camel route,

for example-

*SourceDirectory/file1.xml

SourceDirectory/subDir1/file2.xml

SourceDirectory/subDir2/file3.xml

SourceDirectory/subDir3/subDir4/file4.xml*

should be moved to a destination Directory

*destDir/file1.xml

destDir/file2.xml

destDir/file3.xml

destDir/file4.xml*

The code below copies file including all sub-directories to destination

```
String src="ftp://username:password@host/srcDir/";
String destDir="ftp://username:password@host/destDir/";
fromUri = src+"?recursive=true&delete=true";
        
from(fromUri)
.to(destDir);
```

To achieve this currently I am using ftp client

```
private void moveOverFTP(String from, String to) {
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(from);
            String[] info = url.getUserInfo().split(":");

            ftpClient.connect(url.getHost());
            ftpClient.login(info[0], info[1]);

            String srcFolderPath = url.getPath();
            String targetFolder = new URL(to).getPath();
            move(srcFolderPath, targetFolder, ftpClient);
            
            ftpClient.logout();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
    
    private void move(String srcFolderPath, String targetFolder, FTPClient ftpClient) throws IOException {
        FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles(srcFolderPath);
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            String fileName = file.getName();
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                String tempSrcPath = srcFolderPath + fileName + "/";
                move(tempSrcPath, targetFolder, ftpClient);
                // delete empty directory
                ftpClient.removeDirectory(tempSrcPath);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Moving "+srcFolderPath + fileName +" to = "+ targetFolder);
                ftpClient.rename(srcFolderPath + fileName, targetFolder + fileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help to achieve this in route itself would be appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you are looking for is the `flatten` option, ie.:

```
from(fromUri)
  .to(destDir + "?flatten=true");
```

Comment: Thanks @Kalusn it worked 
I would have explore more!